How would I approach finding the source code for the paper that is being discussed in this article?
I have read a news article relating to recent research into graph theory-based fraud detection using machine learning, but cannot find the source code for the paper discussed. The paper can be found at the link in the news article: https://www.msn.com/en-gb/money/technology/graph-based-machine-learning-for-advanced-cyber-threat-detection/ar-BB1ikP0h?ocid=msedgntp&pc=U531&cvid=51e10207a9354dc5a377eb06cc002879&ei=208.

no researcher is forced to publish any code of his research

There is one good place to look if the paper is in arXiv, and the one you referenced is here. After the abstract there are several tabs, one of which is labelled "Code, Data, Media", which is specifically for linking to additional files, including code implementations.
At this point in time, none of the options show any code available. Whilst it is difficult to prove a negative, it does appear unlikely there is any official public implementation sanctioned by the original researchers.
Note that implementations linked via the supported tools do not have to be supplied by the authors. They can be unofficial implementations created by other people who have read the paper. So if some implementations do appear at any point, you may have to do some work to assess whether the implementation covers the parts of the paper that you care about, and in a way that it is appropriate for you to use.
